# Why does `\x -> f x x` = `join f`?

Tags: function, haskell, monads

I found out recently that the pointfree for `\x -> f x x` is `join f`, and wanted to understand why. I started here:

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

then got stumped because I'm not familiar with the "function monad". Could someone help me with the type derivation that explains the equality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty simple algebraic transformation of the `Monad ((->) r)` on the type level. Watch as we specialize and simplify the type of `join`.

```
join :: Monad m => m        (m        a)  -> m        a
join ::            ((->) r) (((->) r) a)  -> ((->) r) a  -- Specializing
join ::            (r ->    (r ->     a)) -> (r ->    a) -- Infix
join ::            (r ->     r ->     a)  -> r  ->    a  -- Simplifying
```

Answer (score 4):

no deep insights here, but a mechanical explanation.

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

where join is defined as

```
join f = f >>= id
```

substituting definition

```
join f = \x -> id (f x) x
       = \x -> f x x
```

Answer (score 3):

If we substitute `x ->` for `m` in the type of `join`, we get `(x -> x -> a) -> x -> a`. If we apply `f` to that (which I assume has the type `x -> x -> a` for some `x` and `a`), we get `x -> a`, which is also the type of `\x -> f x x`.